# Invoking Drools from EJB

Tags: java, ejb, drools

I am trying to wrap my head around this issue but so far i am unable too. I am invoking drools from my a simple session ejb, passing in the serializable 'fact'. But for some reason which i am trying to decipher the drools refuses to fire any rules(or does it not see the fact i don't know).
I have taken the below steps:

> -I have also configured the Dump directory which creates the java sources from rules. This tells me that the drl is compiled correctly.
>
> -I invoke the same in a simple test program with same 'fact' and drl file the drools fires up and validates the fact.

What am i missing in the EJB approach?
Any suggestions are welcome!
TIA

Comment: Show the code *that does not work* for starting the session, how you create the POJO and insert it as a fact, and the rule that's supposed to fire.

Comment: I was able to resolve by adding a debug event listener which showed that i was missing a run time dependency. Strangely the error only got displayed after adding the debug listener, otherwise it did not show up in the logs.